# Simulate shared_ptr cyclic references

Tags: c++

I wanted to create two objects, sharing a shared_ptr to each other,  to deliberately create cyclic reference case in visual studio , the debugger gone nuts ( as expected , shown in snapshot), but the program still executes (why?) and give result. I wanted to replace the pointer by weak_ptr now, but how ?

```
struct B;
struct A
{
    void print() { cout << "A " << endl; }
    shared_ptr<B> pB;
};


struct B
{
    void print() { cout << "B " << endl; }
    shared_ptr<A> pA;
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<A> a = make_shared<A>(); 
    shared_ptr<B> b = make_shared<B>();

    a->pB = b;
    b->pA = a;
    a->print();
    a->pB->print();

    a.reset();

    b->pA->print();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect it not to exexcute?

Comment: coz debugger ( Microsoft) already gone nuts, shows infinite references ( why IDE don't overflow ) :)

Comment: The debugger is not required for your program to execute. Also a cyclic reference with `shared_ptr` is not supposed to prevent execution

Comment: Debugger should overflow? How IDE is able to handle infinity here?

Comment: "I wanted to replace the pointer by weak_ptr now, but how ?" open source in the editor and replace `shared_ptr` with `weak_ptr`

Comment: @Slava That would not make the code compileable.

Comment: @Slava: thanks , I will try that, but still confuse the difference between weak_ptr.lock()  vs weak_ptr.expired(), both output same. Afraid SO may block me with new question

Comment: @ark1974 then you should put that into your question, our telepathy machine is broken today. And you better make one question per question, either why it still works or what problems you have with using `weak_ptr`

Comment: @ark1974 "but still confuse the difference between weak_ptr.lock() vs weak_ptr.expired(), both output same" have you tried to read documentation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired

Comment: @Slava: Yes I have read, but when I replace one another, the program remains the same.

Comment: @ark1974 by reading documentation I mean comprehend it, I doubt somebody would try to replace `lock()` with `expired()` after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::weak_ptr`, it look like something like:

```
struct B;
struct A
{
    void print() const { std::cout << "A " << std::endl; }
    std::weak_ptr<B> pB;
};

struct B
{
    void print() const { std::cout << "B " << std::endl; }
    std::weak_ptr<A> pA;
};

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>(); 
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();

    a->pB = b;
    b->pA = a;
    a->print();
    auto wb = a->pB.lock();
    if (wb) { wb->print(); } else { std::cout << "nullptr\n"; }

    a.reset();

    auto wa = b->pA.lock();
    if (wa) { wa->print(); } else { std::cout << "nullptr\n"; }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/sbs73X)

Comment: Thanks, it works like charm.